# DataFrame transformations with nested structures

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Spark DataFrame that looks like this:

```
root
|-- employeeName: string (nullable = true)
|-- employeeId: string (nullable = true)
|-- employeeEmail: string (nullable = true)
|-- company: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- companyName: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- companyId: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- details: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- founded: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- address: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- industry: string (nullable = true)
```

What I want to do is group by companyId and get an array of employees per company, like this:

```
root
|-- company: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- companyName: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- companyId: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- details: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- founded: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- address: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- industry: string (nullable = true)
|-- employees: array (nullable = true)     
|    |-- employee: struct (nullable = true)           
|    |    |-- employeeName: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- employeeId: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- employeeEmail: string (nullable = true)
```

Of course, I can easily do that if I just had a pair of (company, employee): (String, String) using map and reduceByKey. But with all the different nested information, I'm not sure what approach to take.

Should I try to flatten everything? Any example to do similar things would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following --

```
// declaring data types
case class Company(cName: String, cId: String, details: String)
case class Employee(name: String, id: String, email: String, company: Company)

// setting up example data
val e1 = Employee("n1", "1", "n1@c1.com", Company("c1", "1", "d1"))
val e2 = Employee("n2", "2", "n2@c1.com", Company("c1", "1", "d1"))
val e3 = Employee("n3", "3", "n3@c1.com", Company("c1", "1", "d1"))
val e4 = Employee("n4", "4", "n4@c2.com", Company("c2", "2", "d2"))
val e5 = Employee("n5", "5", "n5@c2.com", Company("c2", "2", "d2"))
val e6 = Employee("n6", "6", "n6@c2.com", Company("c2", "2", "d2"))
val e7 = Employee("n7", "7", "n7@c3.com", Company("c3", "3", "d3"))
val e8 = Employee("n8", "8", "n8@c3.com", Company("c3", "3", "d3"))
val employees = Seq(e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6, e7, e8)
val ds = sc.parallelize(employees).toDS

// actual query to achieve what is mentioned in the question
val result = ds.groupByKey(e => e.company).mapGroups((k, itr) => (k, itr.toList))
result.collect
```

Results in:

```
Array(

(Company(c1,1,d1),WrappedArray(Employee(n1,1,n1@c1.com,Company(c1,1,d1)), Employee(n2,2,n2@c1.com,Company(c1,1,d1)), Employee(n3,3,n3@c1.com,Company(c1,1,d1)))),

(Company(c2,2,d2),WrappedArray(Employee(n4,4,n4@c2.com,Company(c2,2,d2)), Employee(n5,5,n5@c2.com,Company(c2,2,d2)), Employee(n6,6,n6@c2.com,Company(c2,2,d2)))), 

(Company(c3,3,d3),WrappedArray(Employee(n7,7,n7@c3.com,Company(c3,3,d3)), Employee(n8,8,n8@c3.com,Company(c3,3,d3)))))
```

The important thing is: you can pass any function you want in `mapGroups` to get the groups in a way that you want.

Hope this helps.